# Memory leaks preferring in order to not to slow down shutdown

Tags: c++, performance, memory-leaks, singleton, chromium

[Chromium's documentation says:](https://www.chromium.org/developers/coding-style/important-abstractions-and-data-structures#TOC-Singleton-base::LazyInstance)

> NOTE: Both Singleton and base::LazyInstance provide "leaky" traits to leak the global on shutdown. This is often advisable (except potentially in library code where the code may be dynamically loaded into another process's address space or when data needs to be flushed on process shutdown) in order to not to slow down shutdown.

In which case this is acceptable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Acceptable" is a bit tough to define, as I personally prefer to avoid this practice. For example, we use leak detection tools which would end up showing false positives with this practice unless otherwise suppressed (though I noticed in Chromium's documentation that their leaky traits suppress it: I don't do that and treat false positive warnings as something to fix rather than to suppress).

Naturally this would only be acceptable if the operating systems being targeted reclaim the resources acquired by the singleton when shutting down a process. Most modern operating systems do this though for the most common types of resources. Naturally if your singleton creates a massive temporary file of some sort, it would be wise to destroy it with an explicit shutdown process.

**Shutdown Speed**

The cited reason to simply avoid manually reclaiming resources for speedy shutdown is legit, but it's often accompanied by a mindset which allocates a boatload of memory in the teeniest chunks.

This can often come about when using linked structures or lots of teeny abstract objects allocated individually against a general-purpose allocator. If there's millions of teeny memory chunks to free individually, that can translate to painful shutdown times that span seconds.

Yet the speed of startup, loading input data, and shutting down tend to be often quite related to each other. If we want to speed all of them up, it can be helpful to preallocate and pool memory in bulk.

With this kind of bulk resource-allocation and pooling strategy, applications can start up and shut down and just operate quickly overall. This can be hard to apply, but if you have that going for you, the application will often be able to insta-shut down anyway even with gigabytes of data loaded, and probably simply leaking resources will start to seem more lazy than an optimization technique and maybe push it more towards the aesthetic of being "unacceptable". YMMV.

Yet in cases where there is an actual need for performance, you do what you need to do. I imagine the Chromium developers had their codebase structured in a nature where this was beneficial before designing leaky traits and suppressors for leak detectors. Everyone has a different kind of scenario they're looking at.

**Shutdown Correctness**

In some really complex codebases with a lot of plugins being loaded and unloaded on shutdown, e.g., just getting the damned application to shut down correctly can actually be really hard.

I looked down at a codebase once where we worked ourselves into a corner this way and actually had the bulk of our bugs relating to the application crashing on shutdown (least user-critical time to crash, but terribly annoying nevertheless).

The issue for us was with singletons and other types of globals being created when plugins were loaded which, on creation, triggered side effects to external states (other globals or other singletons living in a different module). In those cases, there was the symmetrical desire to reverse those side effects upon destruction of such a global (ex: removing from a global collection if constructing the global added to one). This introduced the issue of destruction order (which was extremely difficult here due to the decentralized code written by numerous authors and global states dispersed across numerous plugins).

When globals start depending on other globals (lazy-constructed or not) during destruction, things can get pretty awkward just ensuring that things are destroyed in the proper order so that a global doesn't end up relying on another global during shutdown which has already been invalidated (possibly even with the dylib unloaded).

We were almost certainly doing all sorts of things wrong there (starting with using too many singletons and globals and scattering them across plugins in an ad hoc fashion with no unifying design mindset), and this experience made me dislike singletons and globals of all sorts in these kinds of complex scenarios (not for the reduced flexibility, but the difficulty of just writing correct shutdown code), but it probably would have been a lot easier if we didn't bother to try to make these globals reverse side effects to other globals on destruction, to simply leave them there and let the operating system clean up resources. There I could understand the temptation to just leak and not bother to destroy things, or even if we do destroy things, to not reverse side effects to other globals. It's an ugly workaround hack to a very faulty design, but I can understand that kind of issue a little easier than working around performance issues by leaking.

In any case, what's "acceptable" is going to vary a lot. It's going to range from aesthetics all the way to portability concerns. This is the first time I've encountered an efficiency argument for simply leaking singletons, but I can understand what sort of scenarios might lead to that.

Answer (score 1):

When all the memory (and other resources) are reclaimed and released back to the OS at shutdown anyway.  This is what happens on linux systems for instance.